# Automatically Delete a Token that was created after some milliseconds in Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have the following Mongoose Model that I wish to auto-delete after 2mins. Unfortunately, the auto-delete is not working. Note that, I wish to keep the `created_at` field as a `Number` in milliseconds not as a date. How do I go about getting the below code to work for me.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const TokenSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        token: String,
        deleted: Boolean,
        deleted_at: Number, 
        created_at: { type: Number, expires: '2m', default: new Date().getTime() },//Auto-Delete after 2minutes
        updated_at: Number,
    }
);

TokenSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    let shadow = this;
    let now = new Date().getTime();
    shadow.updated_at = now;
    if (!shadow.created_at) {
        shadow.created_at = now;
    }
    next();
});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongoose uses MongoDB [TTL Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/#ttl-indexes) for expiring documents, which only functions on fields containing either a Date or array of Date values.

If the indexed field for a document contains any other type, it will not be automatically expired, so to get auto-expiry working, you will need to have `created_at` store `type: Date`.

MongoDB internally stores dates as the number of milliseconds since epoch, which you can extract with the `valueOf()` method, and the mongo query language permits querying a date field by pass a number of milliseconds.

Comment: I see. Thanks so much for this idea. You are awesome!!!

Comment: Be careful with this when using this approach for email verification. I have an issue where I set my ttl on the token to 1 hour. The token was being created then instantly deleted causing my users to not be able to verify their email and create account. I set my ttl to 72 hours. Timezones matter...